# SAPUI5 demo for non-split application

Tags: javascript, architecture, master-detail, sapui5

There are a lot of demos, tutorials and documentation about SAPUI5 split application but I don't manage to find extensive demo of non-split application. Is it available somwhere?

Why such focus on split applications? They can be great for mobile devices, but there is no need of them for desktop application, I think.

What is the master view supposed to contain? Maybe master view can contain main menu (but then the master view should be located on top part of the page) of the application and the scenario of the master-detail data is only example that is not encountered in reality in the most cases?

There is worklist demo that is quite good.

Answer (score 1):

Because split applications by nature are the most responsive applications (work tremendously well on both desktop as well as all mobile screen sizes)

However, if your focus is purely desktop, then you may want to try out the (non-responsive) [ux3 Shell](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#test-resources/sap/ui/ux3/demokit/Shell.html) or [unified Shell](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ui/unified/Shell.html)